# retrieve all products from subcategories

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is My **Products** Table :

- ID
- name
- category_id

And here is my **category** Table :

- ID
- title
- parent_id

I want to Fetch All Products (by category id) which belongs to a specify category and it's children.

category_id in Products table always refer to a subcategory

I tried **HasManyThrough** but i can't paginate on retrieved products.

Comment: please tell us the query you have tried till now.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for one level of child categories:

```
Product::whereHas('category', function($q) use($categoryId) {
    $q->where('category', $categoryId)
      ->orWhere('parent_id', $categoryId);
})
->get();
```

`category` is `belongsTo` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In Products Controller

   $products= DB::table('products')->select('products.*')
   ->join('categories', 'categories.id' ,'=', 'products.category_id')
   ->get();

//or
//here is using model name also
use App\Products;

   $products= Products::select('products.*')
   ->join('categories', 'categories.id' ,'=', 'products.category_id')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

first in `Category` Model write these methods:

```
public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
}
```

and in `Product` Model:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

now in controller:

```
$res = Category::with([
         'products',
         'children.products'
       ])->find($your_category_id);
```

use `dd($res)` and see the result. hope it works

Answer (score -1):

Fetch all the categories first and loop over it and fetch all the products belonging to that category, and you can limit the number of products per category, let's say 10.

After that, if using for front-end, then use ajax, and for API's directly pass offset, give it an offset of particular amount for particular category.

Hope this helps.